# how can provide access to wp_admin page for non wp_users?

Tags: wp-admin, login

```
function custom_authenticate_username_password($user,$username, $password ) {

        global $wpdb;
        $table_name ='users';
        $sql="select * from $table_name where username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";
        $user=$wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if(!empty($user)){

             echo 'success';


        }

        else{
            echo 'faliure';
        }



}
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );

add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3);
```

here the users table contain some users information.Those users are not wp registered users but i want to provide wp_admin access for those users.How can i do that?

Comment: I don't see 1 valid reason to give visitors access to the admin panel. If you want them to input something, make a front-end form or so where they can submit.

Comment: here i got the users from a different site .I would like to provide admin access for these users like wp_users

Comment: so what is the question? you have the code, and it should work....

Comment: its not working i am not able to get admin access

Comment: i am not wp user i dont have roles and capapbilities . I am the user to some other site but i would like to login wordpress through my details

Comment: how can i authenticate and get cookie to login wordpress

Comment: :( in software there is no such thing as "it is not working" you should describe what happens, what you expect to happen and any debuging attempt you have tried.

Comment: Why not move to a single sign-on plugin instead? That way they can use their existing credentials and not create a new login, but you also won't have to try to get around Core's authentication processes.

Comment: what does mean by core's authentication process

Comment: @MarkKaplun yes i tried when i returning the user in the above code getting error as Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::has_cap() in E:\hema\wamp\www\test\wp-login.php on line 925

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to be able to authenticate a user based on its user/password (or whatever other authentication parameters you use), as user capabilities will be tested all over the code, both on admin and front end, and maybe other user based information like email address, avatar etc.

Therefore you need to simulate all the relevant information, and frankly, the easiest path is to just create the users as proper wordpress users even if you do very little with that information for the users you are interested in.

Or to say it differently, you get the error because your authentication do not return `WP_User` object. You can create a class inheriting it (maybe), but the effort will probably be much bigger than creating a proper user in the DB.

Comment: ok but how can i add user meta information like wp_capabilities,wp_user_roles for my users

Comment: Is there any way to directly provide wp admin session like by  using wp_set_auth_cookie

Comment: @hemaanjali, as I said, you can write your own user class that implements differently the required API, and maybe use filters to provide meta data access when needed, but for example the meta data, where will you store it? It is much easier to just create proper wordpress users